# Excel, find date based on day name in cell

Tags: excel, date

I have table:

[image]

I'm trying to find dates of specific day (here: Monday) in specific month in 5 cells below DATE cell.

For example, Mondays in March - 6.03.2017,  13.03.2017,  20.03.2017,  27.03.2017,

I'm "playing" with it for about 2h, trying week.day, mod, choose and anything iC can find in Google but no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of task can be done more easily by dividing steps. I made an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fyj_mfHy2xEGuqHHlgBHFV0R3mqVTdeJ1SAnwc1XB00/). When you input some values in yellow cells, output(calculated by formulae) will be displayed in green cells. What you really need is `weekday` function, plus I used `date`, `join`, `day`, etc.

[image]

Of course, this can be done via VBA script or Apps Script, which can be undoubtedly much more elegant. I added the script to the above sheet. The red cells are filled by this custom function. Its logic is almost the same as the flow of the sheet.

```
function getDaysWithNames(year, month, name) {
  name = name.slice(0,3).toUpperCase();
  var t;

  //get the first day
  var day;
  for(day=1; day<8; day++) {
    t = new Date(year, month-1, day).toDateString().slice(0,3).toUpperCase();
    if(t == name) break;
  }

  //first three days are always valid because they are <= 21
  var validDays = [day, day+7, day+14];

  //test the fourth day
  day += 21;
  t = new Date(year, month-1, day).getDate();
  if(t == day) validDays.push(day); else return validDays;

  //test the fifth day
  day += 7;
  t = new Date(year, month-1, day).getDate();
  if(t == day) validDays.push(day);

  return validDays;
}
```